# Define style to a p:clock element in primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, clock

I try to put style in a `p:clock element` with class attribute but I receive the following message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Setter not found for property class.

That's another way to define style to a `p:clock` element?

XHTML:

```
<p:clock pattern="HH:mm" class="clock"/>
```

CSS:

```
.clock
{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `class`. For many components you'd use `styleClass` instead, but here you have to do it like this:

```
<p:clock pattern="HH:mm"/>

.ui-clock{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

This way of doing it is described in the User Guide under "skinning".