# how to customize in css/primefaces the p:clock font?

Tags: css, primefaces

I would like to manipulate the font size of my clock, but seems like my css style didn't work well with primefaces?

sample of code:

```
               <div id="day" style="font-size: 12px">
                    text here
                    <p:clock  pattern="HH:mm:ss" mode="server" />                        
                    <p:clock pattern="dd MMMM yy" mode="server" />
                    <p:clock pattern="E" mode="server" />
                </div>
```

this is the sample screen:

[image]

Comment: Should be duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366554/define-style-to-a-pclock-element-in-primefaces/25369436#25369436

Comment: What css style? The font-size: 12x? If so, please learn to use a browser developer tool and the basic about html and css.